# Copying values in a column to another column in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a button that copies all of the cells in one worksheet to a new worksheet.  However I want the Total Quantity (H) column of the first worksheet to go into the Previous Quantity(G) column of the new worksheet. With that I want the Current Quantity (F) column to clear the values. With each new sheet the length of the column could grow so I can't set a specific range.

ActiveSheet.Range("F").ClearContents  ??

Anything I've done has had the copy paste commands and I would prefer a direct method.
Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select an entire column in column F, use

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F1").EntireColumn.ClearContents
```

You can also extend this to EntireRow, etc.

---

**Edit** - now that I'm clear on what you're asking.

If you already have a button that copies the entire worksheet to another one, then I assume that it copies all the original data as well. I don't know exactly what's on your worksheets, but the following code should show you how to copy & paste entire columns.

Assume there are two columns, G and H. The first row of G is named "Previous" and the first row of H is named "Current". The following code replaces column G with column H while preserving the column names in the first row:

```
Sub Test()

    'Clear Column G:
    Range(Cells(2, 7), Cells(Rows.Count, 7)).ClearContents

    'Copy & Paste H to G:
    Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(Rows.Count, 8)).Copy
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'Clear Column H:
    Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(Rows.Count, 8)).ClearContents

End Sub
```

This is *Copy* and Paste. If you have no formulas that need preserving, you can get around all that code by simply Cut and pasting:

```
Sub Test()
    Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(Rows.Count, 8)).Cut
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks yes  - but I'm looking for how to copy the contents of the entire column to another column in a new worksheet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem then. You've already created a button that does just that, right?

Comment: I've created a button that copies the entire worksheet to a new worksheet.  I then want the values in column H (total Quantity) in sheet1 to overwrite the values in column G (previous Quantity) of new worksheet.  The idea is that after the time period (say a month) the user creates a new worksheet for the next time period - where the quantities will be updated. Sorry this is clear as mud

Comment: I've edited my answer, hopefully it's what you need.

Comment: That has helped greatly - I had the column and rows opposite - the only glitch is that the contents are copied to a new worksheet that the user must first rename.  I'm thinking I need to create a variable for the unknown name of the worksheet to paste into?

Comment: You can program your button to first ask the user for a name for the new tab. Then create the new sheet with that name, and your should then "know" what the new sheet is called. You can view this page for how to use VBA to create and name new sheets: http://www.mrexcel.com/td0097.html

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
Columns("F:F").Select

Selection.ClearContents
```

Comment: The ClearContents does work - its the copying from 1 column to the other that isn't working...

Comment: OK, I guess you want to copy from H to G and clear F, is that correct? In that case I think you can do: `Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("F:F").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste`